# SQL Server - Text column contains number between

Tags: sql-server, contains, numeric, between

Can someone tell me how I code in SQL Server so that I am looking in a `varchar` text column to see if it contains a numerical range within the text?

For example, I'm looking for columns that contain anything between `100000` and `999999`. The column may have a value like

```
this field contains a number `567391`
```

so I want to select that one, but not if it had

```
this field contains a number `5391`
```

Comment: Is the text before the number the same for each record? Or can it be any text?

Comment: I can be any text and the number could appear anywhere within it.

Comment: And I guess the text can contain other numbers too I suppose? That would make it difficult to know which number is the correct one. I have an idea on extracting the FIRST number, is that worth posting?

Answer (score 0):

For your given example, you can check the digits:

```
where col like '%[^0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%'
```

This is not a generic solution, but it works for your example.  In general, parsing strings in SQL Server is difficult.  It is better to extract the values you are interested in when loading the data, so the relevant values are correctly in their own columns.

Comment: Thank you - this works.     The column I am analysing is a free text entry field,  it is possible that the user could have entered non-compliant data here,  so this task is part of a clean-up exercise to make the data compliant.   Thank you for your help.